# Conditional parameter type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, types, conditional-statements

I have this function here, where the first argument type depends on whether the second argument is true or false

So if userExists is true, data should be a string, else a number.  But I keep seeing errors.

Can anyone help on where I'm going wrong?

```
type DataType<T> = T extends boolean ? string : number

const makeUsername = async <T extends boolean>({
  data,
  userExists,
}: {
  data: DataType<T>,
  userExists: T
}) => {

  if (userExists) {
    // data type should be string
  } else {
    // data type should be number
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks, like you are trying to build something like:

```
type StringOrNumber<T extends boolean> = T extends true ? string : number
```

But this won't be used in flow analysys. So in `if` block, you won't get correct type infered.

```
function makeUsername<T extends boolean>({ data, userExists }: { data: StringOrNumber<T>; userExists: T }): any {
  if (userExists) {
    // But data here is still StringOrNumber<T>. You have to cast it manually.
    const dataStr = data as string;
  } else {
    const dataNum = data as number;
  }
}

// While on call side it works well
makeUsername({data: '12', userExists: true}) // ok
makeUsername({data: 12, userExists: true}) // error
```

But probably function overloads is more suitable here:

```
function makeUsername({ data, userExists }: { data: string; userExists: true }): any;
function makeUsername({ data, userExists }: { data: number; userExists: false }): any;
function makeUsername({ data, userExists }: { data: string | number; userExists: boolean }): any {     
  if (userExists) {
    // Here you have to cast types anyway...
    const dataStr = data as string;
  } else {
    const dataNum = data as number;
  }
}

// But on call side, this will also works as expected.
makeUsername({ data: 'kyo', userExists: true }) // ok
makeUsername({ data: 'kyo', userExists: false }); // error
```